# php add key value to array

Tags: php, arrays

So i get objects from the database and i want to put the id and the points inside an array.
And everytime getIscorrect equals true the value of the id must be increased by 1.

```
$answers = array();
    $return = $this->_quizMapper->getAll();
    foreach($return as $answer){
        if($answer->getIscorrect() == true){
            if(!($answers[$answer->getID()])){
                $answers[$answer->getID()] = 1;
            }
            else{
                $newPoints = $answers[$answer->getID()] + 1;
                $answers[$answer->getID()] = $newPoints;
            }
        }
    }
```

but i keep on getting error: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: on this line                 `if(!($answers[$answer->getID()])){`

Comment: `var_dump($answer->getID());` to see if it's what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `if (!isset($answers[$answer->getID()]))`

This will suppress the notice.

Answer (score 0):

This is beacuse the key is not defined.

What you should use is:

```
 if(!isset($answers[$answer->getID()]) || !($answers[$answer->getID()])){
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to that:

```
$answers = array();
$return = $this->_quizMapper->getAll();
foreach($return as $answer)
{
    if($answer->getIscorrect() == true)
    {
        if(!isset($answers[$answer->getID()]))
        {
            $answers[$answer->getID()] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $newPoints = $answers[$answer->getID()] + 1;
            $answers[$answer->getID()] = $newPoints;
        }
    }
}
```

You must use the method `isset()` in order to check if the current key exists in the array.